# db2 column level trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

We have following requirement.

TableName : Items ; ColumnName : id,isActivated 
TableName : DeactivatedItems ; ColumnName : id,timestamp

Whenever given 'id' is deactivated , we need to create a entry in the 'DeactivatedItems' table with the 'id' and the timestamp.

For this we wanted to use the columnlevel trigger in DB2.
In reality we have more columns in addition to the id , isActivated columns of 'Items' table.

I have following questions. 
Given that table has many columns , will the update to the other columns also will invoke this trigger ? If yes is there is any way to restrict that.

Also, what is the 'transaction' nature for a given trigger. If trigger invocation fails, does it rollback the update operation as well.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation for the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement?  What did you find?

Comment: If it fails the failure goes back to the user doing the update.  Depends on how your doing commits and such for a roll back.  However if you specify the library/file of table your inserting into and keep things simple it won't ever fail.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the column trigger only triggers when the column is updated.  Include a when clause for a bullet proof solution.

```
CREATE TRIGGER danny117t AFTER UPDATE OF isActivated ON mytable

 REFERENCING OLD AS O NEW AS N 
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL 
--detect change to '0'
WHEN (N.isactivated = '0' and o.isactivated <> '0') 
BEGIN ATOMIC 
--I hope you can take it from here
insert into somefile values(n.id);

END;
```